# Why doesn't Haskell provide folds for one-dimensional Arrays?

Tags: higher-order-functions, haskell

`Data.Array` doesn't provide folds for the `Array` type.

In Real World Haskell (ch. 12), the reason is said to be that `Array`s could be folded in different ways based on the programmer's needs:

> First of all, there are several kinds of folds that make sense. We might still want to fold over single elements, but we now have the possibility of folding over rows or columns, too. On top of this, for element-at-a-time folding, there are no longer just two sequences for traversal.

Isn't this exactly true of `List`s? It's very common to represent e.g. a matrix with a multidimensional `List`, but there are still folds defined for one-dimensional `List`s.

What's the subtlety I'm missing? Is it that a multidimensional `Array` is sufficiently different from an `Array` of `Array`s?

**Edit:** Hm, even *multidimensional* arrays do have folds defined, in the form of instances of `Data.Foldable`.[0] So how does that fit in with the Real World Haskell quote?

[0] http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html

Comment: The difference between multidimensional arrays and nested lists is that all arrays have essentially the same type: `Array Int e`, `Array (Int,Int) e`, `Array (Int,Int,Int) e`….  So you can't make a function which is only defined for one-dimensional arrays, whereas `foldr` takes a list of lists and processes it list by list, rather than concatenating all the lists and processing it element by element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you mention the difference between a "multidimensional" `Array` and an `Array` of `Array`s, that will illustrate the point nicely, alongside a comparison with lists.

A fold (in the `Foldable` class sense) is an inherently linear operation, just as lists are an inherently linear structure; a right fold fully characterizes a list by matching its constructors one-for-one with the arguments to `foldr`. While you can define functions like `foldl` as well, there's a clear choice of a standard, canonical fold.

`Array` has no such transparent structure that can be matched one-for-one in a fold. It's an abstract type, with access to individual elements provided by index values, which can be of any type that has an `Ix` instance. So not only is there no single obvious choice for implementing a fold, there also is no intrinsic linear structure. It does so happen that `Ix` lets you enumerate a range of indices, but this is more an implementation detail than anything else.

What about multidimensional `Array`s? They don't really exist, as such. `Ix` defines instances for tuples of types that are also instances, and if you want to think of such tuples as an index type for a "multidimensional" `Array`, go ahead! But they're still just tuples. Obviously, `Ix` puts some linear order on those tuples, but what is it? Can you find anything in the documentation that tells you?

So, I think we can safely say that folding a multidimensional `Array` using the order defined by `Ix` is unwise unless you don't really care what order you get the elements in.

For an `Array` of `Array`s, on the other hand, there's only one sensible way to combine them, much like nested lists: fold each inner `Array` separately according to their own order of elements, then fold the result of each according to the outer `Array`'s order of elements.

---

Now, you might reasonably object that since there's no type distinction between one-dimensional and multidimensional `Array`s, and the former can be assumed to have a sensible fold ordering based on the `Ix` instance, why not just use that ordering by default? There's already a function that returns the elements of an `Array` in a list, after all.

As it turns out, the library itself would agree with you, because that's exactly what the `Foldable` instance does.

Answer (score 4):

There is one natural way to fold lists, which is `foldr`.  Note the types of the list constructors:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
[]  :: [a]
```

Replacing the occurrences of `[a]` with `b`, we get these types:

```
f :: a -> b -> b
z :: b
```

And now, of course, the type of `foldr` is based on this principle:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

So given the construction/observation semantics of lists, `foldr` is the one that's most natural.  You can read the type as "tell me what to do with a `(:)` and what to do with a `[]`, and I'll get rid of a list for you."

`Array` doesn't have this property; you build an array from an association list (`Ix i => [(i,a)]`), and the type doesn't really expose any recursive structure: one array is not built from other arrays through a recursive constructor as a list or tree would be.

Comment: +1 for "tell me what to do with a `(:)` and what to do with a `[]`, and I'll get rid of a list for you." - i really like it!